# Nexus One stuck in a reboot loop after a failed system update

Tags: updates, nexus-one, device-firmware, boot-loop

I think that the device may have lost power during a system update and it now won't boot. It sticks in a reboot loop.

Can I re-flash it easily? I suspect the firmware is broken.

Comment: I would try -- what do you have to lose? If you have a custom recovery on it, you could also try wiping the Dalvik cache. And if nothing from both helps, a factory reset might do (beware this deletes all your data and apps, too).

Comment: Izzy - How would I do those things? I'm not familiar with the procedure. I can get to the boot loader but nothing else.

Comment: How did you do it in the first place? Was it an OTA, or did you manually flash an `update.zip`? I never applied any OTA, but if it did not complete, the downloaded `update.zip` (if the OTA used this way) might still be present. I would first check its time stamp (e.g. via `adb shell`), and if that matches, simply re-apply it via the recovery menu. Maybe a Nexus One user can give you better advice.

Comment: @Izzy: I wasn't the one using the phone at the time but it would definitely have been an OTA.

Comment: Is the phone rooted? Does it have custom Recovery installed? Stock or custom ROM (like CyanogenMod)?

Comment: @Chahk: Unrooted and stock image.